# Jenkins file operations zip: zip the contents of a folder without including the folder itself on Microsoft Windows

Tags: windows, file, jenkins, zip

The current zipped result looks like this:

```
zipped_dir -> folder -> root_folder -> some files
```

I would like it to function like this command:

```
cd folder; zip -r ../zipped_dir.zip *
```

desired result:

```
zipped_dir -> root_folder -> some files
```

Jenkins version  2.72, File Operations plugin 1.6.

Source Code Management: Git

branches to build: `**/tags/production/**`

build triggers: `Poll SCM`

**File operations**

file copy :

include pattern: `application/**`

Exclude File pattern: `<blank>`

Target Location: `${GIT_BRANCH}`

file zip:

Folder Path: `${GIT_BRANCH}`

Comment: Could you provide the configuration, this is clue less what you are using and what configuration you did in Jenkins.

Comment: you could use the command you showed, `cd folder; zip -r ../zipped_dir.zip *`, instead of using the file operation plugin, potentially. this would also make your build job more portable (in case you wanted to move off jenkins some day for some reason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

burnettk had the answer to the question.

post answer, jenkins was installed on windows and required MinGW for the zip command.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Automated%20MinGW%20Installer/mingw-get-inst/

Make sure you have MinGW (usually C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin) in the Path environment variable.

install these packages.

mingw-get install msys-unzip msys-wget msys-zip

It seems restarting the jenkins service made it recognize the path addition.

jenkins could then use the zip command.